# Git Clone Failed

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, git, bitbucket

**Problem**

I am trying to do the clone from `bitbucket`. It is failing.

**Other stackoverflow posts**

I have gone through other stackoverflow posts but could not succeed.
Specifically

1. `shallow/unshallow` has not worked.
2. `PostBuffer` increase to `1 gb` has not worked
3. The `core.compression` is already `0` means disabled but it did not work

**Clone using cmd**

I have tried to go `--depth 1` with `clone` and then `--unshallow` but it did not work.

It gave an error like below when tried `git pull --all`

[image]

**Clone using Eclipse(Spring Toolsuite 3)**

Then i tried to do the clone using Eclipse(Spring IDE) using `ssh` but it still failed with the following error

[image]

This seems like is because of some large object in history.

**Questions**

1. If i am getting this error due to a large object in history, can i remove this? How to do that?
2. Is this a limitation of `git` client I am using or the `Bitbucket` the host of the repository?
3. Should I try some other `git` client to clone/pull the repository

**More Info**

Git Configurations using `git config --list`

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=[CERT FILE]
http.sslbackend=openssl
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
user.email=[EMAIL]
user.name=[NAME]
winupdater.recentlyseenversion=2.23.0.windows.1
core.compression=0
http.postbuffer=1048576000
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=[URL]
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

This repository is not using `LFS`

A **suggestion** I have come across is to use an `older version` of Eclipse that can succeed in cloning. Why is that so?

The error details in eclipse(sts) are as below
[image]

**Spring Tool Suite 4.4.0** has the same error as above, the detail of the env is as below

[image]

Java is 64 bit

[image]

**Some findings/conclusions**

1. The error with `STS` is a limitation of the `JGit` that is used in it as the `Git` client. It has a limitation of size as far as I could understand
2. That error does not occur if i use git from `cmd` or even if use another client `sourcetree`. In this case the error is the other one which says

   `fatal: pack has bad object at offset 90599582: inflate returned 1`

   `fatal: index-pack failed`
3. The eclipse oxygen is able to clone successfully. But it does not make sense what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: looks like you have a 32-bit client which limits your sizes to 2G. Note that your message complains about a 10G chunk. Most likely you need to install a 64 bit version of git and/or eclipse. Also make sure that you use one of the latest git versions.

Comment: I have seen this code file. Line 752 actually throws error. https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/PackParser.java do you think its due to eclipse being 32 bit i m adding to the post the error session data in eclipse sts

Comment: @Serge I have tried with STS 4.4.0 and it failed too with same error.

Comment: You probably have a 32-bit java then. Try a 64-bit installation. make sure that it is picked correctly by eclipse.

Comment: You might take a look at [partial cloning](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html).

Comment: @Serge Java is 64 bit

Comment: just make sure that eclipse init file points to it (-vm).

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting problem (I had the some problem cloning Linux), there are several solutions all of with can be found here:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/big-repositories